# What is the strongest opinion on masah of the neck in the Maliki madhhab?

Tags: wudu, maliki

Some sources write that wiping the neck (masah neck) while performing wudu' in the Maliki madhhab is a makrooh, while others say that it is a Mandub. 
Which opinion is stronger inside the Maliki madhhab?

Comment: Could you cite the source which says that it is mandub?

Comment: I do not remember. In the table on some website it was written that it was Mandub. And what opinion eventually right?